# Expanding Measurable Sets

Tags: measure-theory, fa.functional-analysis

Let $S,T \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be measurable sets, and suppose that there exists a measurable bijection $f\colon S\to T$ so that
$$
\|f(x)-f(y)\| \;\geq\; \|x-y\|
$$
for all $x,y \in S$.  Does it follow that $\mu(S) \leq \mu(T)$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It follows from two observations:

- For Hausdorff meeasure your statement follows from the definition.
- Hausdorff measure = Lebesgue measure (up to constant).

Comment: Note that the assumption that the bijection f is measurable is not needed for this argument.

Comment: @Alex, you need $T$ to be measurable; otherwise you can not write the inequality.

Comment: I wasn't questioning the measurability of S and T. But the measurability of the bijection f is an additional assumption in the question as formulated and is unnecessary.